# Method to send messages to a channel using telegram bot API, python 3 and JobQueue

Tags: python, bots, telegram

Basically I'm trying to understand how this API works, by doing the following .I'm not able to get the message to my channel (I'm sending the /test command from my telegram account). Also, how I'm supposed to use JobQueue and send auto-msgs every 3 hours for example? The documentation explanation doesn't works for me.

```
def test(bot, update):
    update.send_message(chat_id='@channelid', text='this is a test')

def main():
    # Create the EventHandler and pass it your bot's token.
    updater = Updater("457160310:AAFlxrH2uAaOMGrgO0suOXFM2gVKywsUL0E")
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("test", test))

    dp.add_error_handler(error)

    updater.start_polling()

    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Note that you added the token. If it is still valid, consider to change it via @botfather

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the job implementation to send messages on intervals you can read [this page](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-JobQueue)  that is full of examples. Someone should be the very same thing you want to do.

About the command thing, I think that the library doesn’t get commands from channels so you may consider to:

- send the command in private chat to the bot and the bot sends the reply to the channel (better thing in my opinion)
- handle messages from channels (not commands) and checking if the text of the message contains the command

I would suggest the first solution so you can even keep clean the channel

Comment: Yeah, I aware of this page, the problem is that the exemples simply don't work. As for your first consideration, that's the thing I'm trying to do with this code I posted: send the command in private from my personal account, so the bot can, instead of respond to me, respond to the channel.

Comment: @user3927607 for the first thing I don’t see jobs in your code so I can’t say what’s wrong. For the last thing in test function use bot.send_message instead of update. It should work

Comment: using "bot.send_message" fix'd this problem! Many thanks. Now about the job: there's no job in the code because I don't know where to implement it: should I put the job in the main function and make this job call another function (test for exemple)?

Comment: That's it, I fixed the problem by adding a job in the main function that calls the test function :) thanks for the help!!

Comment: @user3927607 yes it has to be in the main if it should be run when the bot is turned on.

Comment: @user3927607 if you want the job to be executed with a command, put in the function of a command for example instead of in the main

Answer (score 0):

**You can send messages directly to a channel or a conversation using the Telegram REST API by knowing its chat_id.**
According to the Telegram documentation, methods such as webhooks require users to send a message to the bot first before the bot can reply. These methods essentially aim to obtain a chat_id, which is different for different recipients.

However, if you want to send messages to a specific channel without going through that process, you only need to acquire the fixed chat_id of the channel and the bot's token. Then, you can use curl to send the message:

```bash
// get
curl -i -X GET \
 'https://api.telegram.org/bot{0}/sendMessage?chat_id={1}&text=hello'

// post
curl -i -X POST \
   -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
   -d \
'{
  "chat_id": "{1}",
  "text": "here is bot"
}' \
 'https://api.telegram.org/bot{0}/sendMessage'
```

Please replace {0} with the bot's token and {1} with the fixed chat_id of the channel.

## How to obtain the chat_id of a channel?

You can send the channel's link to the @username_to_id_bot, and it will provide you with the chat_id of the channel.
Link: https://t.me/username_to_id_bot